# Last rows missing in Mysql Table

Tags: talend

I am using Talend to charge a table(Mysql), However there are missing records in the table. I've looked into the Talend Job with `tLogRow` and it says I have all 3650 records while in my SQL Table i find only 3600. Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: look carefully thru your output.  it could be committing say every 100 rows, then something in your last 50 rows is causing an error.  those last 50 then do not get committed.  alternately, try loading just those 50 rows and if they don't load then you have a problem with the data in one of those rows.

Comment: I really can't figure it out it for exemple this the line that appears 72 NV Non ventilés Non ventilés and one is the last record that doesnt show
73 TT Total  Total

Comment: split out the last 50 rows and load only those rows to troubleshoot the issue.  If they load then issue is likely NOT the data.  If they do not load then issue is likely with the data.

Comment: If The problem is with the data what do you think i should do next ?

Comment: find out which row and see what the problem is.  typically its a data type or length.

Comment: I'd enable die on error on the output component.